# Create MongoDB database and set its path to a specific folder

Tags: mongodb

I'm using ubuntu 16.04! Is it possible to change the data directory for a specific database in mongo? I'm trying to setup this [recommendation engine](https://github.com/shivankurkapoor/Raijin-Movie_Recommendation_Engine#raijin---movie-recommendation-engine-developed-using-python-spark-library) and I was asked to create a new MongoDB database and set its path to folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pre-version 3.0.0**, all the databases that one `mongod` hosts have to be in the same dbpath folder which can be set via command arguments using the `--dbpath` flag or the config file.

You could however run multiple mongods and host them individually? either on different ip/ports.

**Version 3.0.0** you can use the `--directoryperdb` flag within the command arguments or config to set multiple directories per database (See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--directoryperdb)

> Uses a separate directory to store data for each database. The directories are under the --dbpath directory, and each subdirectory name corresponds to the database name.

Answer (score 4):

When you start mongod.exe you can set the database path with the

> mongod.exe --dbpath "path to your folder"

setting.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible, run mongod process with [--dbpath](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--dbpath) option